# Fine tuning update query

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I am developing a batch process in the peoplesoft application engine.

I have inserted data in staging table from JOB table.

There are 120,596 employees in total, whose data have to be processed, this is in development environment.

In testing environment, the number of rows to be processed is 249047.

There are many non job data which also have to be sent for employees.

My design is in such way that I will write individual update statements to update the data in the table, then I will select data from the staging table and write it in the file.

The update is taking too much time, I would like to know a technique to fine tune it.

Searched for many things, and even tried using `/* +Append */` in the update query, but it throws an error message, `sql command not ended`.

Also, my update query has to check for nvl or null values.

Is there any way to share the code over stackoverflow, I mean, this is insert,update statement, written in peoplesoft actions, so that people here can have a look into that?

Kindly suggest me a technique, my goal is to finish the execution within 5-10 minutes.

My update statement:

I have figured out the cause. It is this update statement

```
 UPDATE %Table(AZ_GEN_TMP) 
  SET AZ_HR_MANAGER_ID = NVL(( 
 SELECT e.emplid 
  FROM PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES E 
 WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(E.EMAIL_ADDR, 0, INSTR(E.EMAIL_ADDR, '@') -1)) = ( 
 SELECT c.contact_oprid 
  FROM ps_az_can_employee c 
 WHERE c.emplid = %Table(AZ_GEN_TMP).EMPLID 
   AND c.rolename='HRBusinessPartner' 
   AND c.seqnum = ( 
 SELECT MAX(c1.seqnum) 
  FROM ps_az_can_employee c1 
 WHERE c1.emplid= c.emplid 
   AND c1.rolename= c.rolename ) ) 
   AND e.e_addr_type='PINT'), ' ')
```

In order to fine tune this,I am inserting the value contact_oprid in my staging table, using hint.

```
SELECT /* +ALL_ROWS */ c.contact_oprid 
      FROM ps_az_can_employee c 
     WHERE c.emplid = %Table(AZ_GEN_TMP).EMPLID 
       AND c.rolename='HRBusinessPartner' 
       AND c.seqnum = ( 
     SELECT MAX(c1.seqnum) 
      FROM ps_az_can_employee c1 
     WHERE c1.emplid= c.emplid 
       AND c1.rolename= c.rolename ) ) 
       AND e.e_addr_type='PINT')
```

and doing an update on staging table:

```
 UPDATE staging_table
  SET AZ_HR_MANAGER_ID = NVL(( 
 SELECT e.emplid 
  FROM PS_EMAILtable E 
 WHERE UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.email_addr,'[^@]+',1,1)) = staging_table.CONTACT_OPRID 
   AND e.e_addr_type='PINT'),' ') /
```

This will take 5 hours, as it has to process 2 lakhs rows of data.

Is there any way using which the processing can be speed up, i mean, using hints or indexes?

Also, if I don't use this, the processing to update other value is very fast, gets finished in 10 minutes.

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any actual code? It would be tremendously helpful to see what you're doing... generally, 120k records you should be able to update in a few seconds so you're doing something that someone should be able to improve.

Comment: @Ben: The code is SQL actions of peoplesoft application engine, and it is huge. It would be nice if some sort of framework is given to me, so that I can post the code there. The database is oracle. Thanks

Comment: As @Ben suggested, without seeing the code that actually are doing the update we can only guess some options but it would be just guesses.

Comment: @Jorge Campos: I know, and I am ready to share the code. But, that's very huge. It uses %Execute(/) and then, various updates statements.

Comment: I have shared the update query.

Comment: I think that isn't the update that is taking too long, it is your query. Have you tried to take it out and run a Explain on it? Maybe some improvement on the query could improve your update. Other option is to do it through a bulk update.

Comment: Update is taking too long, and I want to fine tune it. I don't have priveleges in the database to update it. And would like to know about bulk update, may be, that might help. As I have process large amount of data. I have not issued commits in between, otherwise, that would have made it slower than at present it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this, used MERGE INTO TABLE oracle statement, and now the process takes 10 minutes to execute, including file writing operation. Thanks all for your help and suggestions.